# Evolution apparently deleting messages from inbox

Tags: email, evolution, delete

I have a user running Evolution on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and with only one account (Exchange MAPI).

The problem is that, apparently, Evolution is deleting emails from the inbox. The user also has a mobile device with a mail client, and I tried sending emails from an external account with the mobile turned off (I suspected that there was something wrong with mobile's mail configuration, like POP3 instead of IMAP or something like that). It turned out that the problem is just Evolution. If I close Evolution and sent test mails to his account, I can see them both in the mobile and in the web client (Microsoft Outlook Web App - OWA).

But when running Evolution, I only can see them just for a second, and then they disappear. Of course, they also disappear from the web and mobile clients (well, they last some time in the mobile client, because of syncing)

Obviously, I asked the user to let down Evolution temporary. Any idea about what to do? This user had been recently migrated from Thunderird, and I'm very reluctant to a new migration, but I can't figure out what the heck is happening with Evolution. First I thought it was some filter which was badly configured, because it doesn't delete just all incoming mail, just some.

The user only has a couple of very simple filters. Then I revised spam configuration, and it seems normal.

I don't really know what to do next. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: So is it fixed? You disabled the Spam filter and it works?

Comment: Sorry, I misexplained it (I'm not a native english speaker). The spam configuration seems normal, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Okay... Is it IMAP that Evolution uses?

Comment: I could also think of the integrated Bayes filter. To narrow it down, you could disable all filters in *edit › accounts › receive* and reset (plus uncheck) the "unwanted" folder in *presets*. The "reset" should take care for the Bayes stuff; I'm not sure how to completely deactivate that (the filter part should do that, though).

Comment: All filters disabled, but the issue remains.

Comment: Sounds like a bug: You may find this useful: https://projects-old.gnome.org/evolution/bugs.shtml